# Trigger in phpmyadmin to prevent more records to be added if they reach a certain limit

Tags: sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to limit the number of records (say maximum 10 records) from being added into my supplier table (see sql below). I am getting error #1064 - "You have an error in "your sql syntax".

```
for each row
begin
    declare cnt INT;
    select count(*) INTO cnt FROM suppliers
    if cnt = 10 then
       signal sqlstate '4500' set MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can store only 10 records.';
     end if;  
end;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Where's the first part of the trigger declaration?

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon at the end of `select count(*) INTO cnt FROM suppliers`

Comment: I tried adding a semicolon at the end of the select statement but am get the same error. I am using EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1. The first part of the trigger declartion is included on the form provided by EasyPHP:
Trigger name: max_count
Table: suppliers
Time: Before
Event: Insert

Comment: Any other way to write this?